# How to calculate the hedge ratio between two securities using the Least Squares model in Java

Tags: programming, statistics, python

How does one, having two lists of prices Y and X and wishing to fit the Least Squares model, perform this in Java?

The fit is required to calculate the hedge ratio in a pairs trading strategy.

For every period, the spread is calculated as follows:

```
symbol1.close - hedgeRatio * symbol2
```

We intend to compare the performance of this formula versus using normalized moving averages.

The below Python code uses the statsmodels library and the Ordinary Least Squares (OLS) method.

```
import statsmodels.api as sm

def hedge_ratio(Y, X):
    X = sm.add_constant(X)
    model = sm.OLS(Y, X).fit()
    return model.params[1]
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question at it has no direct link with quantitative finance. It would be better suites to stackoverflow.

Comment: Indeed not really suited here and this should be googleable: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/userguide/stat.html#a1.4_Simple_regression

Comment: In view of [this topic on Meta](http://meta.quant.stackexchange.com/q/1496/848) this question can probably be on-topic but please explain more about what have you tried and what inputs and expected outputs are. Where do you stuck when you follow the docs?

Comment: Not a Java programmer myself but don't you just need a linear algebra library and compute $b = \left( X^T X \right)^{-1} X^T y$, where $X$ is your design matrix with first column all ones? See e.g. Chapter 3 in Greene "Econometric Analysis".

Answer (score 1):

The below code works for us:

```
    final boolean includeIntercept = false;
    SimpleRegression simpleRegression = new SimpleRegression(includeIntercept);

    for (int i = 0; i < symbol1Bars.size(); i++) {
        simpleRegression.addData(symbol1Bars.get(i).getClose(), symbol2Bars.get(i).getClose());
    }
```

This uses the [Apache Commons Math 3 library](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.apache.commons%7Ccommons-math3%7C3.6.1%7Cjar)